# Why is my webcam showing a surrealist version of the normal video?

Tags: drivers, skype, webcam, conferencing

Here's a screen capture of what my webcam is showing:

[image]

I think it is a driver problem, so I headed for my laptop manufacturer's website: http://acer.com/ and found 3 different drivers for my laptop model (an Acer Aspire 5745G) and downloaded them all not knowing which one is for my particular model. I tried to install any of them, but with no luck.

I also tried to adjust the settings of the webcam via Skype's interface, but after a restart the situation returned to its previous state...

Please help, I really need to be able to make normal video-conferencing using Skype, Jitsi, etc.

Thanks in advance for your answers, they are much appreciated! :)

Comment: Was the webcam working at some point?

Comment: Have you tried to update drivers via "Device manager" on Windows and letting Windows search for best driver? If it does not work, try to uninstall the driver, reboot, and use the ones from Acer. Also, after searching Acer, I see there are three vendors for webcams. You should stick with the drivers to your particular model.

Comment: @Ramhound: It kind of did somewhat, but the background of the video was still surrealist while the foreground was more normal.
NuTTyX: I'll try this and let you know what happened. Also, as I've said in the original post, none of the 3 different drivers of the 3 vendors of webcams installed on my machine, they all said something about "webcam not found" or something like that.

Comment: @NuTTyX: I tried to install any of these webcam drivers for my Acer Aspire 5745G: Chicony, Liteon and Syuin, but all of them thew the following error while trying to install: "Unrecognized camera!".

After another restart, I tried to install the drivers again, and this time, I got lucky with the Liteon driver (if I'm not mistaken), it installed successfully and I think that my webcam is acting MORE normally again. Thanks again for your answers, they were useful for troubleshooting purposes. You can close this question... for now! :D

Comment: Check settings in any software installed with the camera driver - it may be in PAL or SECAM mode when you need NTSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install any of these webcam drivers for my Acer Aspire 5745G: Chicony, Liteon and Syuin, but all of them threw the following error while trying to install: "Unrecognized camera!".

After another restart, I tried to install the drivers again, and this time, I got lucky with the Liteon driver (if I'm not mistaken), it installed successfully and I think that my webcam is acting MORE normally again. Thanks again for your answers, they were useful for troubleshooting purposes. You can close this question... for now! :D

My webcam seems to be working fine with the following settings of Acer Crystal Eye webcam software: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPCxd.png (at resolutions 320x240, 640x480, 1280x800 and 1280x1024).